# Why don't I see flickering in artificial light despite using the wrong framerate?

Tags: framerate

I've read on several sources that when using artificial light, in Europe (50Hz mains frequency) you are supposed to record on 25/50fps or you can induce flickering. Makes sense in theory and all, but I wasn't able to ever reproduce it. I tried with my LED kitchen lightning, my LED studio light and even the halogen bulbs in my bathroom, everything both at 50 and 60fps. No recording shows even the slightest bit of flickering.

Is this normal? Is the flickering effect overstated and actually occurs only in very specific circumstances? Or if not, what could be the reason I don't see it?

(I'm using a Canon EOS200D if it matters. I watched the videos both on PC and camera, and I also double-checked on PC that I got the frame rate on the camera set right, which I did.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using lights which will show up flicker.

Fluorescent lights are the worst, as their light output varies significantly with the mains frequency - so if you record at 60Hz in Europe where the mains runs at 50Hz you will see a very obvious 10Hz beat frequency.

Halogen lights don't really flicker, as the filament remains white hot throughout the cycle.

Good quality LED lights, will have no flicker, and cheap ones, if they do flicker at all, are likely to be at either double the mains frequency or even higher, so you are less likely to see any flicker.